# What is the best architecture for trading terminal orders bots?

Tags: architecture, algorithmic-trading

I'm writing a trading terminal that will have smart orders.
I.e.: orders that recalculate based on the price, orders that trigger only at certain conditions etc.

What I have in mind is: an order bots dispatcher service that will start a worker thread for each order.

A worker will subscribe to an instrument price change (Kafka, MQTT, anything) and will do all the logic inside its thread.

This approach seems ok to me, but maybe I miss something and this can be done in a more right/smart way?

Comment: Is making a new thread for each order scalable enough? What about making a queue with an array and push each order then check each order candle by candle.

Comment: I cannot be an option as a queue (by its definition) involves a delay that is a no-option in trading

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an intriguing question. To see it from a high-level perspective, your design appears to function like an event loop dispatching orders. Each order is executed by a specific worker thread within a pool.

In essence, you are establishing an event publisher ('Event-pub') that pushes events to the loop. Each worker thread in this design can subscribe to instrument price changes through services such as Kafka or MQTT, and implement logic accordingly.

If the 'Event-pub' pushes updates relatively slowly (for instance, every 100 milliseconds due to internet latency), and your trading API can process them faster (within a few milliseconds since it's running on the same server), then you may only need one or a few workers. In this case, a simple message broker should suffice without the need to implement a pool of worker threads.

However, if the 'Event-pub' pushes updates rapidly, with minimal latency on the server side (within a few milliseconds), you might require a properly managed thread pool for your workers.

As per textbook theory, the design largely depends on the difference between the speed of input (event updates) and output (order processing). It's essential to evaluate these factors to ensure optimal performance and efficiency of your trading terminal.

I have personally implemented two approaches. When I implemented the thread-pool, it was because each worker heavily relied on the physical I/O device; however, this wasn't for a trading bot. In the case of the trading bot, I proceeded without the thread pool and instead used a message broker. If I needed more workers, I simply expanded the channels of the message broker and made clones of the same worker.